# Xcode Symbol(s) Not Found for Architecture i386 on iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode8

I have project that worked fine in Xcode4. I am trying to upgrade to Xcode 8.3. The project runs fine on iPhone 5 simulator which is 32 bit architecture. But the project fails to run on any other iPhone or iPad.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode  /DerivedData/Test-xxxxrfwxdtcybcclbezelabexxy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libMapView.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-xxxxfwxdtcybcclbezelabexxy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libMapView.a
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RMMapContents", referenced from:
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RMMapContents", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in TestViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RMDBMapSource", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in TestViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RMPath", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in TestViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RMMarkerManager", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in TestViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RMMarker", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in TestViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RMMapView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in TestViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see   invocation)
```

I tried adding active architecture armv7, armv8, armv6, armv7s but still does not build or run on simulators that is other than iPhone 5.

Comment: Check that the library providing RMMapContents is built for all architectures you run the app on.

Comment: The linker thinks you're building for an i386 target, which is definitely not an arm device.  Can you run on an actual iOS device or is this only about different simulators?

Comment: @PhillipMills I can first build on iphone 5 and then archive it.  I can also run on iPhone 5 simulator.  How do I tell the linker not tob build for i386 target?